# Analog SQL LIKE command for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sql-like, fuzzy-search

Tell me the analog SQL LIKE command for ElasticSearch.

SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM cities where 'blah Chicago blah' LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%');
```

Expected output: [{id: 123, name: 'Chicago'}].

---

This is supposed to be used for fuzzy search of entities in the text.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly wat you need, but we can start from:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": { "default_field": "Name", "query": "Chicago" }
  }
}
```

This query return all documents with the work `Chicago`.

You can modify query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": { "default_field": "Name", "query": "*Chicago*" }
  }
}
```

In this case you get documents with the word `Chicago` and with the words which include word `Chicago` - `ChicagoTown`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used this solution for a while. Probably using a pg_trgm extension is the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Search is not suitable for such tasks (
it's intended to work with text as an array of words, and not as an array of characters).

Now I use the pg_trgm (word_similarity(text, text)) extension for my task.